# Why the drawn lines with LineRenderer seems to be thick in some cases?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When drawing the number 2 it seems like some lines are thick. It didn't happen when drawing the numbers zero and one.

```
private void Two()
    {
        Positions = new Vector3[6] {
            new Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
            new Vector3(1, -1, 0),
            new Vector3(0,-1,0),
            new Vector3(0,-2,0),
            new Vector3(1,-2,0)};

        childNumberGameObject = new GameObject(currentNumberIndex.ToString());

        CheckIfNumberParentExist("Two");

        childNumberGameObject.transform.parent = numberParent.transform;
        childNumberGameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(currentNumberIndex * number_Width, 0f, 0f);

        LineRendererInstance(6);
        InstantiateDots(Positions);
        ++currentNumberIndex;
    }
```

The LineRendererInstance

```
private void LineRendererInstance(int PositionCount)
    {
        LineRenderer lineRendererInstance = childNumberGameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lineRendererInstance.positionCount = PositionCount;
        lineRendererInstance.SetPositions(Positions);
        lineRendererInstance.useWorldSpace = false;
        lineRendererInstance.startWidth = 0.10f;
        lineRendererInstance.endWidth = 0.10f;
    }
```

The InstantiateDots

```
private void InstantiateDots(Vector3[] Positions)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Positions.Length; i++)
        {
            var dot = Instantiate(dotPrefab, childNumberGameObject.transform);
            dot.tag = "Dot";
            dot.transform.localPosition = Positions[i];
        }
    }
```

Screenshot comparison with 0 and 1

[image: Thick]

It looks like in number 2 the top middle and bottom lines are thickers then the lines on the sides.

After changed the start and end width from 0.10 to 0.20

[image: Thick]

Comment: nope the on,y thing that looks weird to me is the middle of 2.  But  out of interest although it will look ugly what happens if you increase the width more do you get more of a "plane" look to the line?

Comment: @BugFinder I added a new screenshot to my question after changed the width from 0.10 to 0.20 on both start and end. It didn't help much.

Comment: Well it does - it is exactly what I suggested, look at the top of the 2, the left is fat, the right is skinny, the line is twisting....   Why its twisting right now is not obvious, but it is twisting, the fatter you make that line the more obvious it would be.

Comment: It looks like your width curve isn't straight. Can you post a picture of your line renderer?